# CI/CD with Jenkins and Vagrant

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, puppet

I wanted to build a Jenkins server which would run test of my puppet code on Vagrant. The issue I found is that the we run our server as VMs already,  either in vmWare or AWS and Vagrant will not work as another virtualisation.

Does anyone have an idea how can I create a test platform for my puppet code. What I want to test the deployment of manifest on the nodes them self i.e. If I deploy a `class web server` or make changes to it I would like to check if it affects/breaks deployment of other classes.

The idea would be to iterate over all the classes/roles and see if the deployments are passing. I would like to make it automatic and independent of our engineers. At the moment we are running manual test with `vagrant up` however there are too many roles to do that by hand.

Any ideas how can I tackle this?

Comment: It is unclear if you merely want catalog compilation testing or full blown acceptance testing. I can get you an answer for either once you clarify. Also, this is really only CI. There is no deployment occurring here.

Comment: What I was after was a test that the puppet runs on all of the nodes (web, db, whatever...) are working and passing. With regards to Vagrant it's not a must, I just though of it since we were using it locally. CI/CD is more of get the pull request from GIT, iterate over the nodes and if no failures mark is OK for merge. We had cases where edits to one node class were breaking something on other nodes, thus the iteration over "all"(1 from each class) of them.

Comment: So I was hoping for a clarification on whether this is catalog compilation testing (maybe even regression testing) or acceptance testing. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: I guess a catalog testing, sorry I'm not familiar with the names of the test as I'm new to this. May be better example would be what I want to catch: `Error: /usr/bin/unzip /root/grails.zip returned 1 instead of one of [0]` or `Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type`

Comment: Ok then just use this inside of Docker, RVM, or rbenv: https://github.com/github/octocatalog-diff. I can expand this into an answer when you confirm it satisfies your needs. Also, you can do individual module compilation testing with RSpec Puppet, but you also said: "I would like to check if it affects/breaks deployment of other classes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [Docker](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/) or [AWS provider](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) for Vagrant.

In case of AWS provider you need to set-up RSync to get your environment into newly launched instance.

If your Vagrant scripts are robust, you can use the same script for both local deployment on your workstation and AWS/Docker deployment on CI server.

There are drawbacks to doing these techniques,  in case of Docker you are limited to the same kernel that Jenkins server is running,  in case of AWS you will incur additional costs.  However, for AWS your don't need to allocate as much resources for your Jenkins server, so you might even save money this way because you will be using paying for extra VMs only when you are running you tests.  Just make sure you will shut them down after you done.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any special reason why you want to use vagrant? I'm not sure if you are setting up your production environment with vagrant or not.

In case you are not bound to vagrant, I would recommend you to think about using a docker image to prepare a lightweight environment to run your setups and verifications in.

When doing your tests, spin up a container from your image that contains your puppet distribution and run your setups/tests inside. If you have special kernel requirements, use a separate jenkins slave/agent machine rather than executing jobs on the jenkins master.

If you are not sure how to get started using jenkins with docker, have a look into the examples section of the [Jenkins Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/#examples). The provided examples are showing the declarative pipeline syntax thats still a bit new. Also consider the collapsed *Toggle Scripted Pipeline* Sections which show the groovy pipeline scripts that are alot more forgiving for jenkins pipeline beginners.

Those should be quite good pointers to get started with running+testing your puppet scripts inside docker. For building and using a docker image there should be more than enough tutorials out there.

Let me know if this was a hint in the right direction or if I mistinterpreted your question.